# with open(title, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_object: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python, list

```
def text_file(*args):
    titles = [*args]
    try:
        for title in titles:
            with open(title, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file_object:
                print(file_object.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Файл не был найден в текущей директории!")
        raise


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = input("Введите названия файлов (без их типа .txt): ").split()
    text_file(arguments)
```

Comment: `print(title, titles)` to see what you're working with…

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. Do not try to fit an entire error message into the question title; instead, use that to summarize *what you are asking*, then *explicitly ask it* in the question. You should have text before and after your code explaining what you are trying to do; and you should [show the complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, copied and pasted, and formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
arguments = input("Введите названия файлов (без их типа .txt): ").split()
text_file(arguments)
```

`arguments` here is a list. You're passing a list into the function.

```
def text_file(*args):
    titles = [*args]
```

And here you're doing a lot of unnecessary things, which in the end means you end up with a list with a list in it. Just change that to:

```
def text_file(titles):
    try:
        for title in titles:
            ...
```